# Внедрение модели кредитного скоринга (Python в PHP)

Tags: php, python, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn

Я работаю финансовым аналитиком в одной кредитной организации, не так давно начал заниматься машинным обучением (да и программированием вообще). Сейчас разрабатываю модель кредитного скоринга на языке Python, с использованием библиотеки scikit learn. Сделал несколько моделей с использованием разных алгоритмов - Random Forest, Gradient Boosting и AdaBoost, осталось их сравнить и выбрать лучшую. Далее встает вопрос о ее внедрении. Система, куда они хотят внедрять, написана на PHP, а модель у меня на пайтоне, язык PHP я совсем не знаю. В общем, как это можно реализовать? Подскажите.

Answer (score 3):

Наиболее очевидные варианты:

- обернуть вашу модель в [микро]сервис и вызывать из PHP любым удобным или принятым в организации способом (REST, Thrift, XML-RPC, что угодно), получив в нагрузку все сопутствующие развлечения: развертывание, журналирование, отказоустойчивость и т.п.;
- вызывать интерпретатор Python с вашей моделью из PHP на каждый запрос, обмениваясь данными через стандартный ввод/вывод; не годится для серьезных нагрузок;
- экспортировать обученную модель, совместно с PHP-командой реализовать работу с моделью на PHP или найти готовую реализацию алгоритма для PHP. (очевидно меньше всего вам подходит)

В любом случае в серьезной организации должен быть кто-то ответственный за архитектуру, и принятие решения о способе интеграции - его обязанность.